# Mosquitto_sub Error : connection refused, IPv6 only

Tags: mqtt, ipv6, mosquitto

I'm trying to communicate between my Ubuntu and raspberry pi3 by subscribing and publishing mosquitto using IPv6.
I disabled IPv4 and am trying to subscribe using the command below:

```
mosquitto_sub -h raspberrypi -p 1883 -v -t "test"
```

The response:

```
Error: Connection refused
```

my mosquitto conf:

```
id_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

#allow_anonymous false
listener 1883
socket_domain ipv6
#listener 1883 fe80::b497:9600:80bf:a56e
```

I have no experience with MQTT protocol, could you help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With Link-Local IPv6 addresses, you need to also use a Zone ID.

Comment: Does `raspberrypi` resolve to an IPv6 address? `mosquitto_sub` does not have a way to force IPv6 so the host name needs to resolve to an IPv6 address and as @RonMaupin said for a link-local address it will need to include the `%eth0` interface identifier

Comment: Is your MQTT Broker listening on IPv6 address?  In the log file, you should see something like this on startup:  `Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883`

Comment: If you're just getting started with Mosquitto & MQTT, and great resource is Steve's Internet Guide:  http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-broker/

Comment: Thank you @hardillb it works with this command: `mosquitto_sub -h "fe80::b497:9600:80bf:a45e%enp0s25" -p 1883 -v -t "test"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hashed out in the comments

To use a link-local ipv6 address you must include the interface identifier on the end of the address.

```
mosquitto_sub -h "fe80::b497:9600:80bf:a45e%enp0s25" -p 1883 -v -t "test"
```